# In java i am trying to insert same Integer in a list

Tags: java

In Java I am trying to insert the same Integer in a list, but it's not working.  My code:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list.add(1);
}

for ( int i = 0;i<5; i++) {
    System.out.println(list.indexOf(i));
}
```

Output:
-1
 0
-1
-1
-1

Comment: what can be it's probable reason

Comment: You should be getting `0` as the second index printed, all others `-1`; it should find `1` at the expected index `0`.

Comment: on my machine, this code outputs `-1
0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1`. So this question should be closed as offtop (unable to reproduce).

Answer (score 4):

The output is correct as you are looking for the index of the value 0 to 9 which are not present, except for `1` so it will print `-1`,

http://ideone.com/yGQwR2

prints

```
-1
0
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
-1
```

From the Javadoc for [List.indexOf(int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-)

> Returns the index of the first occurrence of the specified element in this list, or -1 if this list does not contain the element. More formally, returns the lowest index i such that (o==null ? get(i)==null : o.equals(get(i))), or -1 if there is no such index.

What you intended is likely to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

Another way to do this is

```
list.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: don't they add `1` five times? so the second line should be `0`

Comment: it also return the same result -1 0 -1 -1 -1

Comment: @user3593301 this is to be expected as explained.  What did you expect as the output?

Comment: i want  my output  1 1 1 1 1

Comment: @user3593301 in that case you should read the second half of my answer which will do this.